# How do I use the whitespace analyzer correctly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently having an issue where I cannot search for UUID's in my logs. For instance, I have a fieldname "log" and in there is a full log, for example:

```
"log": "time=\"2022-10-10T07:46:00Z\" level=info msg=\"message to endpoint (outgoing)\" message=\"{8503fb5a-3899-4305-8480-6ddc0f5df296 2022-10-10T09:45:59+02:00}\"\n",
```

I want to get this log in elastic search, and via Postman I send this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "log": {
                "analyzer": "whitespace",
                "query": "8503fb5a-3899-4305-8480-6ddc0f5df296"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 50,
    "from": 0
}
```

As a response I get:

```
{
    "took": 930,
    "timed_out": false,
    "num_reduce_phases": 2,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 581,
        "successful": 581,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

But when I search on "8503fb5a" alone, then I get the wanted results. This means the dashes are still causing issues, but I thought using the whitespace analyzer should fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

These are the fields I have.

[image]

Comment: can you share index mapping and setting

Comment: I have added a mapping to my original post but I don't know what you mean by "setting". The wanted UUID is located in "log"

Comment: Is this index is created by Elasticsearch with default mapping or you had some mapping defined yourself?

Comment: I think this is a default mapping. The "log" is a text type, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not required to use `whitespace` analyzer.

You have 2 option to search entire UUID.

First, You can use `match` query with `operator` set to `and`:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "log":{
        "query": "8503fb5a-3899-4305-8480-6ddc0f5df296",
        "operator": "and"
      } 
      
    }
  }
}
```

Second, You can use `match_phrase` query which will search for exact match.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "log": "8503fb5a-3899-4305-8480-6ddc0f5df296"
    }
  }
}
```